# Not seeing value of a shared_ptr, but see it when dereferenced

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

I have a variable which is shared_ptr to an object. It shows "Null value returned for children" in the debugger, but if dereference the pointer I can see the variable.

```
auto varA = std::make_shared<ClassA>( ...);  // this one doesn't show
ClassA dereferenced = *varA;  // this one shows in the debugger

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ClassA>> m_myMap; 
// this is what I want to look into, gives the same error as shared_ptr
```

Similar thing happens with a collection where I store pointers - I can't look inside to see what's stored there.
Is there a way to alleviate this?

This is in CLion running under Linux, if this matters.

The toolchain I use:
Build type: Debug

Toolchain info:

Cmake: /usr/bin/cmake3

C++ compiler: clang++

Debugger: /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/bin/gdb

Comment: How are you compiling your code?  Do you have the debugging information enabled?  The debugger should be able to see the internal structure of the shared pointer.

Comment: I enabled debug (build type - debug) in the toolchain I use and the result is the same

Comment: `ClassA dereferenced = *varA; ` is a bit more subtle, you see a COPY of what varA points to. (at least it proves varA points to some instance because a copy could be made).

Comment: @RomanGoyenko Ask the debugger to print the expression `*varA` or `varA.get()` and it should give you the correctly-typed result just fine.

Comment: The problem I have is not with that variable but with a map that stores these pointers and I can't access the map - it gives the same error when I try looking into it (but thanks, the dereferenced trick works for a variable)

Comment: Not sure you can look at a shared pointer and get anything meaningful *without* dereferencing it. These things are not meant to be observed directly, at least in a debugging capacity, though a clever debugger could dereference for you and show the contents at the destination pointer.

Comment: You could try printing `m_myMap.at ("some_key").get ()`

Comment: @user17732522 are you sure `std::shared_ptr` uses type erasure? The implementations I've seen just store the pointer directly https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/76cc78dc53c21ee413bf0dc7c4d0e96f630be5fb/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h#L474 and I've never had any problems examining their contents with gdb

Comment: @AlanBirtles For the deleter it should use type erasure. But for the pointer to the referenced object it shouldn't, right.